# How can I disallow to use my own annotation for all classes instead of classes implementing concrete interface

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following code. I need to allow usage of this annotation (CommandName) ONLY for classes-instances of ICommand interface. How can I do it?

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // Make this annotation accessible at runtime via reflection.
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})       // This annotation can only be applied to class methods.

public @interface CommandName {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In compile time, you cant do that. In runtime, just check the classes - which is annotated by CommandName annotation - if they are implementing the ICommand interface.